# Grub error solution not working for me

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, grubrescue

I have Ubuntu as the only os. I am trying to fix the grub error.
The command ls give (hd0) only,

Command 'set' give:
Cmdpath=(hd0)
Prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
Root=hd0,msdos1

So I did this:
Set root=(hd0,msdos1)
Set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
Insmod normal

Now, insmod normal say; no such partition.
I have also tried:
Insmod (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/normal.mod
It gives the same response.

How to is solve this?

Comment: This article may help you. https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/

Comment: This article is more likely to help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair